# Stuttering While Walking

Tags: ps4, far-cry-4

I just got the skill "Non-Stop", which lets me sprint infinitely and move faster while crouched. This is great and all, but now when I try to walk normally, I will move very slow. I may move normally for a few seconds, but I will start moving slowly, as if I'm crouching. It will also kick me out of a sprint to make me move slowly.

Has anyone else experienced this bug, and perhaps knows a fix or workaround? I know the PS4 is limited for this, but it's quite an annoying bug.

Comment: I would try uninstalling any updates and try to play the base game offline before any updates are installed. If it still isn't fixed and you have the digital version, I would recommend a full uninstall/reinstall (back up your save data to a USB)

Answer (score -3):

From a personal experience, this is likely the result of a faulty controller. I know it's not a "Hey do this and you're good"  kind of awnser,  but if you have compressed air cleaner,  try spraying some air into the joy stick area,  it is possible that some dust/dead skin/worn down plastic managed to get into the joystick area and is causing the odd behavior. If this continues,  try either another controller,  or uninstalling and reinstalling the updates (be sure to back up your save to PSPlus or to a flash drive just in case)

Comment: This was not a faulty controller issue. No other game exhibited symptoms like this, nor did using another controller fix the issue. It's not really important now, I've finished the game; the issue seemed to very rarely occur a few weeks after this post.